# Build slice by slice a heatmap in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to build slice by slice a heatmap. How can I update the data present in the graph without generating a full figure? The following code each time produces a new plot. I tried to use fig.update_traces() but it didn’t work.

What am I missing?

Thanks

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import time
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1,100))


for i in range(0,10):
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1,100)), ignore_index = True)
    time.sleep(1)
    fig = px.imshow(df)
    fig.show()
```

Comment: The problem is that `fig.show()` will open an html file in your browser, and adding traces won't update the html live. if you're intending to animate a heatmap by drawing each row one at a time, you might consider looking into [plotly animations](https://plotly.com/python/animations/)

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for your answer. I had a look at the plottly animation that indeed look like the perfect tool for me. Nevertheless all the example I found first generate a big dataset and then show slice by slice the result. In my case I do not have the full dataset at the beginning so I would have to generate the new slice at each animation step. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: i haven't used plotly animations before, but I would be happy to try to help and post an answer later